# Couchbase SDK 2 : bulk read operations , how to failover to replicas

Tags: java, couchbase, reactive-programming, rx-java

We are in the process of refactoring a benchmark tool migrating from Couchbase Client 2 to new CouchBase SDK 2.

Previous version has following "bulk get" logic to retrive keys in bulk and if it fails reading from the master, there is a failover to read from the "replicas"

**Legacy code :**

```
List<Map.Entry<String, OperationFuture<CASValue<JsonNode>>>> futures = new java.util.ArrayList<>(keys.size());
                for (String key : keys) {
                    futures.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(key, client.asyncGets(key, transcoder)));
                 }
                Map<String, Long> casValues = new java.util.HashMap<>(keys.size(), 1f);
                for (Map.Entry<String, OperationFuture<CASValue<JsonNode>>> e : futures) {
                    String key = e.getKey();
                    OperationFuture<CASValue<JsonNode>> future = e.getValue();
                    try {
                        CASValue<JsonNode> casVal = future.get();
                        if (checkStatus(future.getStatus(), errIfNotFound) == OK) {
                            result.put(key, JsonByteIterator.asMap(casVal.getValue()));
                            casValues.put(key, casVal.getCas());
                        } else {
                            return ERROR;
                        }
                    } catch (RuntimeException te) {
                        if (te.getCause() instanceof CheckedOperationTimeoutException) { ///READ FROM REPLICA
                            log.warn("Reading from Replica as reading from master has timed out.");
                            // This is a timeout operation on a read, let's try to read from slave
                            ReplicaGetFuture<JsonNode> futureReplica = client.asyncGetFromReplica(key, transcoder);
                            result.put(key, JsonByteIterator.asMap(futureReplica.get()));

                        } else {
                            throw te;
                        }
                    }


                }
```

**Using new Couchbase SDK2**

According to the new Couchbase 2 SDK docs ,
 http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.0/documents-bulk.html

I have following logic to retrieve in bulk.But I am not quite sure where to add the failover mechanism to read from "replicas" using

> bucket.async().getFromReplica(key, ReplicaMode.ALL);

```
List<RawJsonDocument> rawDocs = idObs.flatMap((keys)->{
            Observable<RawJsonDocument> rawJsonObs = bucket.async().get(key, RawJsonDocument.class);
            return rawJsonObs;
        }).toList()
          .toBlocking()
          .single();
```

How can I implement this "read from replica" failover mechanism with the new RxJava based CouchBase SDK  ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the anwer :

```
Observable<RawJsonDocument> rawDocs = idObs.flatMap((key)->{
            System.out.println("key "+key);
            Observable<RawJsonDocument> rawJsonObs = bucket.async().get(key, RawJsonDocument.class);


            return rawJsonObs.onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<RawJsonDocument>>() {

                @Override
                public Observable<RawJsonDocument> call(Throwable t1) {
                    if (t1.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException) { //we have a timeout
                        return bucket.async().getFromReplica(key, ReplicaMode.FIRST, RawJsonDocument.class).first();
                    }
                    throw OnErrorThrowable.from(t1);
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: **that looks like the correct way to do it**. even more idiomatic rx would be to replace the throw with a `Observable.error(t1)` I think, but that's minor. Side cool tip: sometimes you get an `OnErrorThrowable.OnNextValue` from rxjava, know that it usually wraps the value that caused the problem so your code can inspect it :)

Comment: You are using `first()`. This will **throw**, resulting in an `onError`, if no value is emitted, which is a possibility if the key doesn't exist.
You may want another behavior in this case? Other options are `takeFirst()` that will just result in an **empty** observable or `firstOrDefault(null)` that will **emit `null`** instead of throwing (or whatever default value you pass to the operator).

Comment: oups, meant `take(1)`, not takeFirst()